# Convert html to pdf using jspdf in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, jspdf

I have a div tag with all the content which i need to convert to pdf. It is a report layout.

The function below is found inside the .ts file which is called on a button click. On button click the id of the div tag is given to the function to get all the html elements as content to be exported as pdf.

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
 @ViewChild('pdfTableJspdf', { static: false }) pdfTableJspdf!: ElementRef;
     downloadAsPDF_UsingJsPdf() {
      let pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
      pdf.html(this.pdfTableJspdf.nativeElement, {
      callback: (pdf) => {
          pdf.save('sample.pdf');
        },
      });
    }
```

Problem encountered is that the library jspdf is unable to export the whole content with its appropriate layout.
My requirement is to export a given html element to pdf without using autoTable and canvas.

Comment: Maybe you can give `html2canvas` a try and add the content as image to the pdf. Otherwise you need to setup a special print layout page and print the full layout, because otherwise all the styles in header part of the dom is missing.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. When using html2canvas the layout was successfully exported but   it is not what am looking for because it prevents the user from selecting a text in the pdf. Is there another approach how the same thing can be done?

Comment: Well. I guess you need to define a print layout route to generate the pdf and then go back. But this only works if all content is in one page in the correct layout. This is something i am doing. This works fine, if the content is not so much. In some of my use cases i am using a hybrid approach generating the html in der angular application, send the suff to server and generate the pdf using headless chrome. In all cases you need to understand how the styling in angular application works and what it means to put a html element from dom to jspdf ...

Comment: The only way is see would be that all the styling is made inline. No global layout, no component layout. Or add special styleshot to jspdf.you could try to "copy" style on the fly.

Comment: Did you try html2pdf library?